# Rishi Bharadvaj's association to Saamveda

Tags: vedas, rishi, sama-veda

Some say Bharadvaj Rishi was a main contributor to the Saamveda. But the vedas that we know are composed by Rishi Ved Vyasa. So how Rishi Bharadvaj is related to Saamveda ?

Comment: Vedas are not composed by Veda Vyasa.. Vedas are authorless/aapaurusheya... They were just compiled or arranged by Veda Vyasa...

Comment: @Tezz Sorry for using wrong word. I know that. Vedas are authorless, limitless, we can restrict them to the number of 3 or 4. My intent there was referring to Rishi Ved Vyasa's work on Rig,Yaju,Saam and atharva veda.

Comment: No, you are not understanding... read answers given here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/774/how-did-the-vedas-in-hinduism-come-into-existence

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>**Note**: This is the partial answer which explains it's association with Rigveda and *possibly* with Samaveda.</sup>

Visit [How did the Vedas in Hinduism come into existence?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/774/277) and some [information](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15722/277) on Rigveda.

**Bharadwaja is the Drashta (seer) of 6<sup>th</sup> Mandala of Rigveda.** There are 765 mantras of Bhardvaja. Bhardvaja's sons are also seers of some vedic hyms. Also note that most of the Samaveda verses are primarily derived from Rigveda.

> अविन्दन्ते अतिहितं यदासीद्यज्ञस्य धाम परमं गुहा यत्।
>   धातुर्द्युतानात्सवितुश्च विष्णोर्भरद्वाजो बृहदा चक्रे अग्नेः॥ १०.१८१.०२
>
> These sages found what lay remote and hidden, the sacrifice's loftiest secret essence.
>   From radiant Dhātar, Savitar, and Viṣṇu, from Agni, **Bharadvāja brought the Brhat**.

**Bharadvaja has assimilated Brihat-Sama & he was Sama-Gayaka**

There is a description of Bharadvaja found from [Rik Tantra of Samaveda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratishakhyas#Sama_Veda) and [Aitareya Brahmana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aitareya_Brahmana).

From [Aitareya Brahmana](https://archive.org/stream/aitareyabrahmana04hauguoft/aitareyabrahmana04hauguoft_djvu.txt):

> 21.
>
> (He now repeats) a hymn, addressed to Brahmanaspati. * Qandndm 
>   tvd ganapatim havdmahe (2, 23) Brahma is Brihaspati ; by means of 
>   Brahma he thus cures him (the sacrificial man, who had been torn to 
>   pieces). The verses beginning with prathascha L461 yasya saprathascha 
>   ndma (10, 181, 1-3) are the three Gharmatanu^ mantras ; by repeating 
>   them the Hotar provides the Pravargya man with a body, and a form. 
>   (For in the fourth pada of the first of these verses), there is said : " Vasia- 
>   tha brought the Rathantara Sama," and (in the last half verse of the 
>   second Gharmatanu mantra is said), **" Bharadvaja made the Brihat 
>   Sama out of Agni."** ^ By repeating these mantras, the Hotar provides * 
>   the Pravargya man with the Rathantara and Brihat-Samans (required 
>   for its prosperity).

Brihat Sama is considered supreme among Saman hymns (BG 10.35).

Gautama, Vamadeva, Bharadvaja and Kashyapa are considered four primary Saama Gayaka (singer).
<sup>Note: Brief information on [Saama Gana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15304/277).</sup>

Bharadvaja has also given [Srauta Sutra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalpa_%28Vedanga%29#.C5.9Arauta_Sutras) and [Grihya Sutra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalpa_%28Vedanga%29#Smarta_Sutras) to [Yajurveda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yajurveda#Srautasutras)