# In which book Udgeeth is mentioned?

Tags: yoga, yoga-sutras, pranayama, hatha-yoga

**Udgeeth** involves chanting of AUM (OM) with every exhalation.

We do **Udgeeth** in a sequence of Pranayam like **Bhastrika, Kapalbhati, Anulom Vilom, Bhramari** and then **Udgeeth**.

Is **Udgeeth** one of [Pranayam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pranayama)(One of 8 limb of [Ashtanga yoga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashtanga_(eight_limbs_of_yoga)))?

In which book **Udgeeth** is mentioned? I guess its not mentioned in [Yoga Sutras of Patanjali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga_Sutras_of_Patanjali) and [Hatha Yoga Pradipika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatha_Yoga_Pradipika).

Comment: Does this help? https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15304/8735